# Android Studio con base de datos sqlite

Tags: android

Hola estoy empezando a programar en android studio realizando un proyecto de facultad, tengo un activity_layout que contiene un editext(fecha), editext(horadesde), editext(horahasta) y un spinner con datos almacenados y un botón guardar.

lo que estoy intentando guardar son los editex,la selección del spinner en el botón  guardar, agradecería una ayuda o algún ejemplo de como realizarlo [image: app]

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se trabaja con editex, para obtener el texto que ingreso el usuario puedes utilizar el método `getText()`, pero puede que el usuario no ingrese ningún texto entonces este método puede retornar null, entonces lo puedes validar con el método `Objects.requireNonNull()`

```
EditText emailInput
String email = Objects.requireNonNull(emailInput.getText()).toString();
```

En el caso del Spinner puede utilizar le método `getSelectedItem()` y puedes agregarle la misma validación por si no se ha seleccionado nada.

```
Spinner spinner
String nombre = Objects.requireNonNull(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
```